# Unable to change margin-bottom property (CSS)

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

I am currently working on a website, trying to write the client-side from scratch without frameworks. But, for some reason, I am not able to change this margin-bottom property. I just want to put some space in between the h1, h3, h4, h5, and p elements. I used Eric Meyer's reset as well.

**index.html**

```
<body>
        <header class="container">
            <h1><a href="index.html">Jack's Music Portfolio</a></h1>
            <a href="aboutme.html">
                <h3>Some Header</h3>
            </a>
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                <a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a>
                <a href="popularlyrics.html">Popular Lyrics</a>
                <a href="songstories.html">Song Stories</a>
                <a href="contactme.html">Contact Me</a>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <section class="container">
            <h3>Driven to write music that brings <em>impact</em>.</h3>
            <p>Curabitur ut tempus enim. <strong>Introduce the Portfolio here</strong>. Nullam eget efficitur massa, nec imperdiet turpis. Nulla facilisi. Nunc faucibus lectus non cursus fermentum. Cras venenatis, urna sed fermentum gravida, enim lacus fringilla dolor, in cursus arcu diam id lectus. Nulla facilisis nisi est, et rutrum ligula dictum vitae.</p>
            <a href="contactme.html">Contact Me</a>
        </section>

        <section class="container">
            <section>
                <h5>Songs</h5>

                <h3>Song#1</h3>
                <p>Cras venenatis, urna sed fermentum gravida, enim lacus fringilla dolor, in cursus arcu diam id lectus.</p>

                <h3>Song#2</h3>
                <p>Cras venenatis, urna sed fermentum gravida, enim lacus fringilla dolor, in cursus arcu diam id lectus.</p>
            </section>
        </section>

        <footer class="container">
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                <a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a>
                <a href="popularlyrics.html">Popular Lyrics</a>
                <a href="songstories.html">Song Stories</a>
                <a href="contactme.html">Contact Me</a>
            </nav>

            <small>&copy Jack D. MUSIC</small>
        </footer>

    </body>
```

**main.css**

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
    margin: 0 auto;/*top and bottom 0, left and right auto*/
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    width: 960px;
}


h1, h3, h4, h5, p{
    margin-bottom: 25px;

}
```

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**
I found out what was wrong. I am not entirely sure what the logic behind it is, but basically, if I put the link to the reset.css in the HTML before link to the main.css, it works (not the other way around). It also works if I put the reset css code into the main.css in the beginning before the styling css code.

Comment: You may add a snippet so we can figure it out. hmm or you may try to add `!important` after your `25px` (e.g. `margin-bottom: 25px !important;`)

Answer (score 0):

the headers are already had its designated css so you need to override it by using `!important` that way your just adding or editing a function/style to already made style

```
  h1, h3, h4, h5, p{
        margin-bottom: 25px !important;

    }
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.